# from a table I am getting the count and dayname between the dates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Monday 3 
Wednesday 5
Thursday 4
Saturday 3
```

but if there is no record for particular date I am not getting the Dayname as 0 or NULL. I want to print the dayname with count 0

Comment: Please show us your query, sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need  a list for all the dayname  and join your result

```
    select t1.day_name, ifnull(t2.my_count,0)
    from  (
      select 'Monday' day_name
      union 
      select 'Tuesday' 
      union 
      select 'Wednesday' 
      union 
      select 'Thursday' 
      union 
      select 'Friday' 
      union 
      select 'Saturday'
      union 
      select 'Sunday' 
    ) t1
    left join (
      select dayname(my_date_col) day_name, count(*) my_count
      from my_table 
      group by dayname(my_date_col) 
   ) t2 t1.day_name  = t2.day_name
```

Comment: Thanks ScaisEdge for your help. The query works perfectly just need add ON at t2 ON t1.day_name = t2.day_name